# Windows Mobile 7 sending Radio signals

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

Is it possible to send radio signals with custom frequency??

I need some library which allows me to get phone's radio transmitter and some manipulations with device

Note:
I am trying to create RC helicopter controller for Windows Mobile, 
my phone model is LG C900

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 doesn't support this kind of feature. I'm not even sure if Windows Phone 8 does...